# Firestore FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security, angularfire2

I'm having a problem with my Firestore security rules. I have the following rules:

```
rules_version = '2';

service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    function isOwner() {
      return get(resource.data.owner).id == request.auth.uid;
    }
  
    match /projects/{project} {
        function isMember() {
        return /databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid) in get(/databases/$(database)/documents/projects/$(project)).data.flatMembers;
      }
    
      allow create: if request.auth != null;
      allow read: if isOwner() || isMember();
      allow write: if isOwner();
            
      match /sprints/{sprint} {
        allow read: if request.auth != null;
        allow create, write: if request.resource.data.startAt < request.resource.data.endAt;
      }
      
      match /backlog/{task} {
        allow read, create: if request.auth != null;
        allow write: if isMember();
      } 
    }
  
    match /users/{user} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
      allow create;
    }
  }
}
```

They seem to work in the Firestore rules playground. They succeed when I expect them to, but in my application I get the following error:

```
ERROR FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.
at new e (prebuilt-ac190846-5fb4dac2.js:188)
at prebuilt-ac190846-5fb4dac2.js:10430
at prebuilt-ac190846-5fb4dac2.js:10431
at e.onMessage (prebuilt-ac190846-5fb4dac2.js:10453)
at prebuilt-ac190846-5fb4dac2.js:10370
at prebuilt-ac190846-5fb4dac2.js:10401
at prebuilt-ac190846-5fb4dac2.js:15132
at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone-evergreen.js:372)
at Zone.run (zone-evergreen.js:134)
at zone-evergreen.js:1276
```

My question basically is: is there anything wrong with my rules? Why do they succeed in the playground? How can I debug these rules? Currently it is a pain in the ass.

The code that is failing because of permission errors is the following:

```ts
return this.firestore.collection<Project>('projects', query => {
  return query
    .where('members', 'array-contains-any', [
      { user: this.authService.getCurrentUserRef(user), role: MemberRole.OWNER },
      { user: this.authService.getCurrentUserRef(user), role: MemberRole.DEVELOPER },
      { user: this.authService.getCurrentUserRef(user), role: MemberRole.CLIENT }
    ])
    .where('archived', '==', archived);
})
  .snapshotChanges()
  .pipe(mergeMap(projects => {
    return combineLatest(projects.map(project => {
      const data = project.payload.doc.data();
      return this.userService.one(project.payload.doc.data().owner.id).pipe(map(owner => ({
        id: project.payload.doc.id,
        name: data.name,
        owner: owner?.displayName ?? 'Unknown',
        ownerId: owner.uid,
        description: data.description,
        status: data.status,
        archived: data.archived
      })));
    }));
  }));
```

PS: I can edit a single project view in my application, just not the all projects view even though I have where filters which check if you are a member/owner of a project.

Comment: I suggest you include the following information so that the community can help you:  

1) The structure of your database.  
2) The use case that you are trying to achieve.  
3) A minimal reproducible code snippet since the one included is just a snippet of the code that is failing and does not help reproduce the error or understand what you are trying to achieve.  

Also, to debug your code, I recommend that you add log statements to find out which exact rules are failing or get more details about the error, such as knowing if you are authenticated with the correct user.